# Update privilege description for tag wiki edits (5000 rep)

Tags: feature-request, privileges-page

The [privilege description](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) page says that

> In addition, users with this privilege level also get access to the suggested edits queue. The queue has a list of posts which have been edited upon by users who don't have edit privileges. This queue can be accessed over at the suggested edits tab in the review section.

Right now the required rep level is actually lower, at least on StackOverflow (somewhere between 2000 and 3000, I can't find a link right now).

Comment: No, the suggested edit queue is only available for 5k users. You can approve suggested edit at lower threshold, but you need to be lucky to visit a question/answer with one.

Comment: @nhahtdh I only just reached 5k on SO, but have been visiting the [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits) tab for quite some time. Or did things change in the last few days?

Comment: Looks like anyone can see it in the new review page, even logged-out users

Comment: Here on Meta, I see the queue is available to 2k+ users. No sure about SO.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I mean I was actually approving and rejecting edits.

Comment: @LevLevitsky You'd always been able to do that at 2k, you just couldn't see the list of suggested edits, so it was hard to actually find them. Now it looks like everyone can see the list (but you still need 2k to actually act on them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page to review the suggested edits requires a reputation of at least 2000, and that is true for every Stack Exchange site. I took this screenshot on Programmers, where my reputation is lower than 2000.

[image: screenshot]

Maybe we should wait the new review page is not considered beta anymore, just in case the reputation requirements get changed before the review page is considered definitive.

I have removed that part from [the privilege page on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), which is the site containing the master pages that are then pushed to the other Stack Exchange sites. In the case the reputation requirements for that review page are changed back to the old ones, it is still possible to rollback the changes to that page.